# Is there a specific name for two relationships between two tables in database?

Tags: sql, database, erd

I have two tables in a database Faculty and Project. In project table there's a supervisor id and co-supervisor id which acts as a foreign key in project table and  both are referenced to Faculty Id in Faculty table. Simply I have two one-to many relations in my database between these two tables. My question is that Is there any specific name we used to call this type of relationships?

Answer (score 0):

Faculty has an ”one to many” relationship with Project.

Comment: Yes! and there are two "one to many" relations b/w these two table. Is there any specific name for this?

Comment: I'm not aware of a name for that.